# Using replace() function to replace multiple texts(strings) at once in Python

Tags: python, replace

Here's my code:

```
start_j = raw_input('Enter a name: ')
start_j = start.replace("A", "J")
start_j = start.replace("B", "J")
start_j = start.replace("C", "J")
print "Your name is " + start_j
```

Is there anyway to put all the alphabets in one list so that I wouldn't have to repeat the same process again and again until I reach letter "Z"
I tried using loops, but I still can't seem to get the right way to do it.

Here's a scenario:
The user will be prompted to input a name.
If the name contains a letter other than "J", it will be automatically replaced using the replace() function.
Hence it will print out the input starting with J

Here's an example:

```
site = raw_input('Enter your website: ')
site = site.replace("http://", "")
site = site.replace("https://", "")
site = site.replace("ftp://", "")
print "Your website is: " + site
```

An expected input would be http://www.google.com
So the expected out would become:

```
Enter your website: http://www.google.com
Your website is: www.google.com
```

I'm looking for a way to put "http://", "https://", "ftp://" all in one list so I wouldn't have to enter

```
site = site.replace("something", "something)
```

many times

Comment: Post some sample input and output. It'll clear things up.

Comment: Oh wow, your edit really changes the question a lot. Your original question was far from clear enough.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. It's 5 am in the morning and I haven't slept in a while.

Comment: @MarkByers, It seems like the same question to me before vs after the sample/example/illustration. Can you help me figure out what or how i was reading the question wrong before the sample if you understood it differently?
I ask this because i am working on bettering my requirement discerning skills, to  better read a given requirement document or may be even trying to look at them from a different perspective. This may sound weird but i promise you it is not and it really matters in work env and especially for me. ty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
remove_from_start = ["http://", "https://", "ftp://"]
for s in remove_from_start:
    if site.startswith(s):
        site = site[len(s):]
        break
```

Or a regular expression based solution:

```
import re
regex = '^(https?|ftp)://'
site = re.sub(regex, '', site)
```

Comment: start_j is variable that requires an input which would be the name.
If any name starts with a letter other than "J", it will be automatically replaced.

Comment: @MaxWayne: Starts with? `replace` examines the entire string, not just the first character.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex to replace all of the letters at once:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[A-Z]', 'J', 'This Is A Test Name')
'Jhis Js J Jest Jame'
```

---

(After edit): You can use `.startswith()` and string slicing:

```
>>> name = 'A Name'
>>> 
>>> if not name.startswith('J'):
...     name = 'J' + name[1:]
... 
>>> name
'J Name'
```

Although I'm not sure why you'd even need to check with `.startswith()`. Either way, the result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

site = raw_input('Enter your website: ')
# input http://www.google.com or https://www.google.com or ftp://www.google.com
site = re.sub('^(?:https?|ftp)://', '', site)
print "Your website is: " + site
```

Answer (score 0):

use a dictionary:

```
In [100]: import string

In [101]: dic=dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_uppercase,"J")

In [104]: start_j = raw_input('Enter a name: ')
Enter a name: AaBbCc

In [105]: "".join(dic.get(x,x) for x in start_j)
Out[105]: 'JaJbJc'
```

**Edit:**

```
In [124]: dic={"https:":"","http:":"","ftp:":""}

In [125]: strs="http://www.google.com"

In [126]: "".join(dic.get(x,x) for x in strs.split("//"))
Out[126]: 'www.google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

use re, dict and lambda:

```
import re
replacte_to = {
    "http://": "",
    "https://": "",
    "ftp://": "",
}
re.sub("^(ht|f)tps?://", lambda match: replacte_to[match.group(0)], YOUR_INPUT_STRING)
```